# Link Tables in QlikView in qvs

Tags: qlikview

I Have two qvd files Users and Cases.
In Cases I have three fields "creator", "modifier" and "owner". All of this fields are id from Users table.
In my LinkTables.qvs file I join Users to creator by this schema

```
LOAD  'USERS' as TYPE, 
%USER_ID 
Resident USERS; 
Concatenate 
LOAD
'CASES' as TYPE, 
%CASE_ID, 
CASES.CREATOR as %USER_ID 
Resident CASES;
```

My question, how can I join same object (Users) to Cases in other fields. (%User_Id I define in load from qvd script) 
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of a `concatenate load` it might be better to use a `JOIN`. I struggle a bit understanding your data structure. The tables you load have two names in common (thus two keys), namely: TYPE and %USER_ID. Maybe you can clarify your question a bit further and include a few lines of your data.

Comment: Thank you I am also change the structure of my project from conatenate to Join tables in SQl level.